# How to initialize an array of pointer inside a struct by using struct constructor?

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, initialization

I tried `memset` like

```
struct TreeNode {
    bool exist;
    bool word_ending;
    TreeNode* branches[3];
    TreeNode(): exist(true), word_ending(false) {
        memset(branches, NULL, sizeof(branches));
    }
};
```

but there appears warnings

```
warning: implicit conversion of NULL constant to 'int' [-Wnull-conversion]
        memset(branches, NULL, sizeof(branches));
        ~~~~~~           ^~~~
                         0
1 warning generated.
```

Is there some other way to initialize the array of pointer to `NULL`?

Comment: `TreeNode* branches[3] = {};` in the declaration.

Comment: Isn't NULL equivalent to 0?

Comment: If you change NULL to 0 in the source it will compile fine. But just do what NathanOliver suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `memset` we can initialize the array in the member initialization list.  If we use

```
TreeNode(): exist{true}, word_ending{false}, braches{} {}
```

Then  `braches` will be zero initialized.  This works because each missing initializer in a initialization list causes the corresponding element to zero initialized.

Comment: Thanks! But how to initialize branches with nullptr? It is not same as 0.

Comment: @danche 0 is the null pointer.  `nullptr` is just 0 casted to the pointer type.

Comment: so we don't need `branches{nullptr, nullptr, nullptr}`?

Comment: @danche You can but you don't need it.  `braches{}` will do exactly what you want.

Comment: `braches{}` is essentially `braches{0, 0, 0}` which is essentially `branches{nullptr, nullptr, nullptr}`

Comment: @danche No problem.  Glad to help.